# Jenkins Ubuntu wrong versioning?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, jenkins

I just wanted to install the Jenkins Blue Ocean plugin which, according to the installation guide, requires at least Jenkins 2.7. I am currently on version 2.60.3 so I tried my usual `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but it told me I was already on the newest version. So I tried `apt-cache policy jenkins` and I realised that **2.60 is indeed newer than 2.7**.

[image]

But if you check the package website you can clearly see that 2.7 was meant to be the newest version.

[image]

I am not an server expert so I was wondering if this is actually an issue of the Jenkins package right there and if so (and also if not so) how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well *60* is bigger than *7* which indicates that your installed *2.60.3* version is newer than *2.7*.

The list in your browser is just not sorted correctly. Look at the timestamps *Last modified* and you will see which are the latest files.

Comment: Feeling a little bit stupid now after trying to fix this for two hours.. didn't look at the timestamps at all.. anyways thank you man!